# Printers setting disappeared, cannot manage printers, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, settings, system-settings

I was following [these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/) to install canon mp495 network printer on ubuntu 14.04. 
Those instructions did not work, so I went back to manually install it via the printers setting in ubuntu's system setting.
However, there is no printers option anymore. It is simply disappeared.

[image]

What has happened and how can I get it back?

Comment: Is `cups`installed and working? What does `ps aux | grep cups` provide? And `sudo service cups status`? Try `sudo service cups restart`.

Comment: Yes, it is running. `cups start/running, process 2934
`. I restarted it, but didn't help.

Comment: Can you verify that `system-config-printer-gnome` is installed?

Comment: Ah, that was the problem. It was unisnstalled for some reason. Reinstalling `system-config-printer-gnome` solved the problem. Thanks! Feel free to add the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please verify if `system-config-printer-gnome` is installed. It provides the config-gui you are missing.

By standard you can access your `cups`backend also via http://localhost:631/admin

Comment: Thank you! Any reason why `system-config-printer-gnome` could have disappeared?

Comment: Did you uninstall `pip` by any chance?